# What is the difference between a mosaic chart and a tree-map?

Tags: statistics

[Chart given on test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFf9J.png)

I was given a chart on a test and asked to identify what kind of chart it is. I called it a treemap and I got that answer wrong because the professor said it was a mosaic chart. I was under the impression that those two are interchangeable. so what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

> "Mosaic plots assume that every level of one grouping variable can be
> combined with every level of another grouping variable, whereas
> treemaps do not make such an assumption. Treemaps work well even if
> the subdivisions of one group are entirely distinct from the
> subdivisions of another."

*Wilke, Claus O. Fundamentals of data visualization: a primer on making
informative and compelling figures. O'Reilly Media, 2019*